# starting and ending index retrieval of a JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, text

Is there any way to find out the index of the start and end letter's index of a selection in a JTextArea of text?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. You can use [getSelectionEnd](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#getSelectionEnd%28%29) and [getSelectionStart](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#getSelectionStart%28%29).

Answer (score 3):

Doesn't  `getSelectionStart` and `getSelectionEnd`, acording to [the documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html), gives you that information ?